# Retrieve the emails from a google contact group

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-api, google-contacts-api

I'm trying to retrieve the emails from a personal group of a google user.
I'm using the Api Contacts V3 and I can retrieve the contacts and the groups of an specified user (not the domain groups, with the Admin api).

I have read the API and I have tryed several methods, but I can't get the emails of the differents members of a group.

I need help.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've received the contacts, as you said you have done, you can loop through each contact and extract the email. Here's some sample code taken from [the docs](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#retrieving_all_contacts):

```
URL feedUrl = new URL("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full");
ContactFeed resultFeed = myService.getFeed(feedUrl, ContactFeed.class);
for (ContactEntry entry : resultFeed.getEntries()) {
    for (Email email : entry.getEmailAddresses()) {
        if (email.getPrimary()) {
            System.out.print(" " + email.getAddress());
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your response. I Get the contacts without problems and the groups too. The problem is to retrieve the membersof those group. Regards